# Receiving an empty or filled map although it's filled for sure

Tags: go

I have a map as follows:

```
groupMemberStore map[groupMemberId]*groupMember
```

and it's initialized like that:

```
ih.groupMemberStore = make(map[groupMemberId]*groupMember)
```

And I have a RWMutex to synchronize read-write operations. So the problem is, I populate the map with an element and 1 or 2 out of 10 times it is coming as empty even though I know that there's a record.

```
func (ih *IgmpHandler) GetGroup(ctx context.Context, groupId uint32) *igmpca.Group {
    group := &igmpca.Group{}
    ih.mapMutex.RLock()
    defer ih.mapMutex.RUnlock()
    log.Println("gms: ", ih.groupMemberStore)
    for k, v := range ih.groupMemberStore {
        log.Println("k.ipAddress:", k.ipAddress)
        id, err := ih.deviceConfigurator.getGroupId(ctx, k.ipAddress)
        fmt.Println("err: ", err)
        fmt.Println("groupId in GetGroup", groupId, id)
        if err == nil && groupId == id {
            member := &igmpca.Member{
                GemPortId:    v.gemPortId,
                IntfId:       k.intfId,
                SrcIpAddress: v.ipv4Src.String(),
                Vlan:         uint32(v.vlan),
                IsV2:         v.isV2,
                OnuId:        k.onuId,
                UniId:        k.uniId,
            }
            // group := &igmpca.Group{}
            if group.Members == nil {
                gid := &igmpca.GroupId{Id: groupId}
                members := &igmpca.Members{}
                members.Members = append(members.Members, member)
                group.Id = gid
                group.GroupIp = k.ipAddress
                group.Members = members
            } else {
                group.Members.Members = append(group.Members.Members, member)
            }
        }
    }
    if group.Members != nil {
        group.Members.NumberOfMembers = uint32(len(group.Members.Members))
    } else {
        log.Println("EVET NIL", group.Members)
    }
    log.Println("GetGroup -> ", group)
    return group
}
```

The line I print `log.Println(ih.groupMemberStore)` returns `map[]` somethimes and sometimes returns the relevant information. However, during all the invocations I'm sure that there's no delete operation on this map or anything like that. Is there someting I'm missing? Is something related to Mutexes or pointers?

Below functions represent the operations on `groupMemberStore` as get, write and delete respectively.

```
func (ih *IgmpHandler) getFromGroupMemberStore(key groupMemberId) (*groupMember, bool) {
    ih.mapMutex.RLock()
    g, exists := ih.groupMemberStore[key]
    ih.mapMutex.RUnlock()
    return g, exists
}

func (ih *IgmpHandler) writeToGroupMemberStore(key groupMemberId, value groupMember) {
    log.Println("writeToGroupMemberStore")
    ih.mapMutex.Lock()
    ih.groupMemberStore[key] = &value
    ih.mapMutex.Unlock()
}

func (ih *IgmpHandler) deleteFromGroupMemberStore(key groupMemberId) {
    ih.mapMutex.Lock()
    delete(ih.groupMemberStore, key)
    ih.mapMutex.Unlock()
}
```

This is the `getGroupId`

```
func (idc *IgmpDeviceConfigurator) getGroupId(ctx context.Context, groupIp string) (uint32, error) {
    idc.lock.RLock()
    defer idc.lock.RUnlock()
    gId, exists := idc.groupIdMap[groupIp]
    if !exists {
        return 0, fmt.Errorf("group-not-found-for-%s", groupIp)
    }
    return gId, nil
}
```

Comment: Where in the code do you think that you're updating the map? And if you are, why would you rely on the `RLock` and `RUnlock` methods (read-only lock) as opposed to `Lock` and `Unlock` (write)?

Comment: What do you mean by why would you rely on the `RLock` and `RUnlock`?

Comment: Let me ask you this: is `GetGroup` meant to update the map or not? If not, you should add whatever code/method/function meant to update the map.

Comment: Ok, I've added them.

Comment: GetGroup is mean to retrieve the group information. FIrst it check whether a given id exists then returns group itself.

Answer (score 0):

This should be cause of race condition. Please follow as below.

```golang
// NewIgmpHandler creates an instance of IgmpHandler.
func NewIgmpHandler() IgmpHandler {
    return IgmpHandler{
        groupMemberStore: make(map[groupMemberId]*groupMember),
    }
}

// OR

// NewIgmpHandler creates an instance of IgmpHandler.
func NewIgmpHandler(groupMemberStore map[groupMemberId]*groupMember) IgmpHandler {
    return IgmpHandler{
        groupMemberStore: groupMemberStore,
    }
}



// Add adds a group member to the map.
func (ih *IgmpHandler) Add(gid groupMemberId, gMem *groupMember) {
    
    ih.mapMutex.Lock()
    defer ih.mapMutex.Unlock()
    
    // Add new element to the map here. When you are updating the map, you 
    // should take the write lock and It prevents others to read the map.
}

// GetGroup returns igmpca.Group by group Id.
func (ih *IgmpHandler) GetGroup(ctx context.Context, groupId uint32) *igmpca.Group {

    ih.mapMutex.RLock()
    defer ih.mapMutex.RUnlock()

    group := &igmpca.Group{}
    
    for gid, gMem := range ih.groupMemberStore {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: How is this different from what I'm doing?

Comment: You are taking the correct lock when you are reading. Because of that, error should be with writing part. You should take  ih.mapMutex.Lock()
  and defer ih.mapMutex.Unlock() when you write. Over here it is acting as the Write Lock.

Comment: I'm already doing like that in `writeToGroupMemberStore` function. Is that what you're pointing out?

Comment: Yes, Exactly! Please use `defer` to execute ih.mapMutex.Unlock().

Comment: It has no effect whatsoever.